Ties without second note on the piano?
I was going through older scores and found some pieces where I found passages like the following one:

How would you interpret this notation?
Those ties don't look like slurs to me, because there are always multiple of them, which would be unnecessary, and the shaping doesn't look like a slur either.
However, they don't lead to any other notes. The only time I've seen this type of tie without any following notes is on some other percussion instruments, but never on the piano.
Was this just notated incorrectly, or do they have an actual meaning?

These older questions seem to be about the same thing: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/is-this-a-tie-or-a-slur-or-something-else
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/130828/notes-tied-to-rests

What piece/composer? That will allow for detail to be added to the answer, because I/we can look up a better-engraved edition.

@Aaron or, better still, possibly a manuscript.

This may be a lot more meticulous than we're giving it credit for.  The tied G is clear.  E slurs up to F (its line is cut short to avoid the ♮ sign) , then back down to E.  C slurs down to B♮, G is added underneath, that dyad slurs up to C.   The only actual fault might be that the slur from F down to E starts a bit low.
Here it is split over two staves.  Can you do a better job of getting it onto one than the original example?


I wouldn't even say the tied G is that clear, because it looks like it's in voice 1 with the stem going up and I don't see a dot either. So it doesn't look like a tie to me, but just another slur. But pretending it is actual a tied note, I probably would've gone with anything like this: https://i.imgur.com/xIAkmeZ.png

Please read my answer, concerning the G note. Agree or not? As your G is shown as a dotted crotchet.

@Tim Yes, I think tying it to the next G is the intention, making it in practice a dotted crotchet.  It's not meticulous notation.  But if you try to notate it as a dotted crotchet while keeping the information that it's to be played with the right hand, you'll see why the engraver took that route.

@Andy See my other comment.   Your solution groups the G with the left hand notes.   You can have meticulous duration information or you can assist the player with which hand plays what.  The engraver made a decision, and not an unreasonable one.

I'm saying that the Gs are not tied, as there's no dot after the 1st , making that particular mark a slur.

@Tim  Yes, that is the literal notation.  However a slur makes no musical sense there.  And, I repeat, let's see your attempt at notating it with a dotted crotchet?

That third G is a red herring. It's written as a quaver, to go with the C note above it. But then it has a line joining it to the same G in the next bar.
One has to look very carefully to see that, but because it's too short to reach the end of the bar, (the note value, that is!),even, it cannot be a tie.
All the other notes are joined by a slur, which makes sense, as they're different notes and all fulfil their full value in each bar, in 6/8 timing.
Please read this answer very carefully before deciding to dv, as it's caught out Laurence.

They are slurs, just badly printed. When a composer wants a legato connection between notes in two adjacent chords, there must be a slur between each one, because it's possible to slur some of the chord tones but not others.
